# How does Ctrl + K work in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, design, javascript

I am very curious to know how to implement the `Ctrl-K` (code sample) feature against code.

For example:

```
public static void main(String args[]){        
    System.out.println.out("welcome");
}
```

Will that be nicely formatted?

1. Do we require any package to implement this?
2. Any ready made code available to do this?

I am planning to develop a site where this feature would be really helpful.

Comment: Why in the world did this get moved to meta? Sure--it's "about" Stack Overflow, but I'm kinda thinking that answers involving event handlers and cross-browser Javascript libraries belong exactly where the asker asked this, and not here...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot understand how the Ctrl+K works in Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187446/cannot-understand-how-the-ctrlk-works-in-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 3):

I guest you are looking for [Google Javascript code prettifier](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html).

As [rsp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185541/rsp) mentioned in comments it works for the [following list](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tests/prettify_test.html) of languages.

Comment: @Gierlik, does that work for all the languages

Comment: @harigm, look at the test page: http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tests/prettify_test.html