# Cannot understand how the Ctrl+K works in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, code-formatting

How does the code  work with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>? I am new to Stack Overflow.

I can't get it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>. I 
press space button for 4 times in each line I post.

Comment: You have to highlight the code before pressing Ctrl+K, in case you haven't done so.

Comment: Are you on a Mac? It's Cmd-K on OS X.

Comment: Nope i am working on windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write code -> Select code -> Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> button -> finish!

Or

Write code -> Select code -> Click `{}` (situated above textarea)-> finish!